# Hide Button based on the result in Partial view MVC

Tags: c#, html, .net, user-interface, model-view-controller

I have a parent.cshtml page where it renders a partial view called _child.cshtml. This _child.cshtml contains a datatable and displays the data in the grid. Whenever this datatable doesn't contain, I need to hide the button which is in parent.cshtml. Please help me out how can I achieve this.

I have tried the below so far in parent view

```
jQuery.ajax(type: "POST",
        url: "{ChilePartialView}",
        data: { data },
        success: function (response) 
        {
            if (!response.Product.Count > 0) {
                jQuery("formSaveButton").hide();
            }
        });
```

Also I have tried the below as well:

> ```
> jQuery(document).ready(function () {
>     $.get('/ControllerName/ActionMethodName', function (data) {
>         if (!data.Products.Count > 0) {
>             $("formSaveButton").hide();
>         }
>     });
> ```

But none of them worked

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show your research?

Comment: @JordanRieger, I have edited my main post. I tried the JQuery to get the response from the partialview. But not sure how this will work. Can you please help me out what wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that actions of your controller basically return just html markup (if only you don't explicitly return other ActionResult, for example JSON). You can't work with this markup in a way like

```
if (!data.Products.Count > 0)
```

Any JS script you insert to the child view will be just rendered as part of your html page and can hide any element from the page - it doesn't matter if hidden element is in parent or child view on the server side. Therefore you can just insert to your child view an inline script that will hide selected element in $(document).ready listener.

A bit more accurate solution uses sections (see for example [this artice](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor)) and allows to output all inline scripts in one place (usually before closing body tag).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you guide me how can I insert an inline script? Please don't mind as I am totally newbee.

Comment: @user2083386 just as a script in html, i.e. <script>$(document).ready(function(){});</script>